# How data is shared between composables

Tags: vuejs3, composable

I am using using vue3 composable. I understand that when you use composable, there are ways to declare it as a global variable and to use it as a parameters. What is the difference between these two, and which way do you prefer?  here is an example:

### global variable

---

**test-A.js**

```js
import { composableB } from './test-B.js'

export function composableA () {
  function increase () {
     const {data} = composableB()

     data.value++
  }

  return {
    increase
  }
}
```

**test-B.js**

```
const data = ref(0)

export function composableB () {
  return {
     data
  }
}
```

**use template**

```
import {composableA} from './composable/test-A.js'
import {composableB} from './composable/test-B.js'

const {data} = composableB()
const {increase} = composableA()
```

### parameters

---

**test-A.js**

```js
export function composableA (data) {
  function increase () {
     data.value++
  }

  return {
    increase
  }
}
```

**test-B.js**

```
export function composableB () {
  const data = ref(0)

  return {
     data
  }
}
```

**use template**

```
import {composableA} from './composable/test-A.js'
import {composableB} from './composable/test-B.js'

const {data} = composableB()
const {increase} = composableA(data)
```

I want to know what's different. And which way do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

`tl;dr`: First example is a **global variable(local store)**, the second is not.

They basically behave differently and are not the same. based on your need you can use both. I have provided two online examples for both senario you check them out.

The first example(`test-b.js`) is a global variable and acts like a store(Vuex or Pinia), because the reactive variable defined outside of the composable so it declares once and can be shared everywhere.

[Look at this in playground for example 1](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) (globla reactive variable)

The second example(`test-b.js`) is not a global variable or store, it is just a composable with its own reactive variable inside of it. You can call it and get a new reference every time! and the increase function belongs to the ref that is passed to it. I think `test-A.js` here(this simple example) is just a helper function and does not do anything to with reactivity.

[Look at this in playground for example 2](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)